# Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS Xcode 13.2.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am facing below error when I am running my app with Xcode 13.2.1

example.xib:1:1: Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS.

I tried too many solutions for this but still error is not fixed.

Error Report as below:

Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS. (Failure reason: IBAgent-iOS (13961) failed to launch and exited with status 6): Failed to launch IBAgent-iOS via CoreSimulator spawn: Failed to handshake with platform tool (Failure reason: Failed to keep platform tool alive): Failed to keep launch platform tool and keep alive: Failed to communicate with helper tool (Failure reason: The tool closed the connection)

Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=IBAgent-iOS (13961) failed to launch and exited with status 6, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbfcf4117a0 {Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Failed to launch IBAgent-iOS via CoreSimulator spawn" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to launch IBAgent-iOS via CoreSimulator spawn, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbfe404f070 {Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Failed to handshake with platform tool" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to keep platform tool alive, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to handshake with platform tool, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbfe5d227a0 {Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Failed to keep launch platform tool and keep alive" UserInfo=0x7fbfd4446f40 (not displayed)}}}}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash reports for "IBAgent-iOS" for further information., NSLocalizedDescription=Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS.}

Comment: Hi Pramod, unfortunately there's not enough information to help you here – what were you doing when the error occurred? How can we reproduce it to see what's going on? Do you have any other pieces of the error message like the stack trace?

Comment: Error message like this only. When I am trying to run my application when upgraded to Xcode 13.2.1.